# How to create user defined function using variable in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a UDF to get full_name in snowflake with the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST (LAST_NAME char(100),FIRST_NAME char(100))
   
RETURNS CHAR(1000)
   AS
'declare
 FULL_NAME varchar;
 begin
 FULL_NAME := FIRST_NAME || '' '' || LAST_NAME;
 return FULL_NAME;
 End';
```

*I am getting Compilation of SQL UDF failed: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 1 unexpected 'FULL_NAME'. error*

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Snowflake Scripting block is not necessary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LASTNAMEFIRST (LAST_NAME char(100),FIRST_NAME char(100))
RETURNS CHAR(1000)
AS
' FIRST_NAME || '' '' || LAST_NAME';
```

Call:

```
SELECT LASTNAMEFIRST('a', 'b');
-- b a
```

---

If the BEGIN/END block is required then stored procedure is the way to go:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LASTNAMEFIRST (LAST_NAME char(100),FIRST_NAME char(100))
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
declare
 FULL_NAME varchar;
begin
 FULL_NAME := FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME;
 return FULL_NAME;
End;
 $$;
 
CALL LASTNAMEFIRST('a', 'b');
-- b a
```

Comment: Hi @LuKasz, I want to use a variable in that case. because similar code with stored procedure working fine.

Comment: @mahadevdhyani [General Usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-introduction.html#general-usage): "A SQL UDF evaluates an arbitrary SQL expression and returns the result(s) of the expression." - keyword **expression**. Snowfalke Script block is not expression. Please post your exact requirement, if you need Snowflakce Script block then Stored procedure is way to go

Comment: Thanks, @Lukasz Szozda, can we use a variable to store this inside of UDF?

Comment: @mahadevdhyani I do not believe it is possible to use `BEGIN END` block as expression in the context of SQL UDF.

Comment: Hi @Lukasz Szozda, without begin end block can we pass this to a variable?